# Return characters before and after white space

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I am trying to retrieve address data. There is currently an issue with the data where an address will display the house number twice. For example "9 9 House Road". I would like to identify all the street address that ave two numbers at the start like "9 9". So i would like to return it only if the first two characters are one the same and two are both numbers.Any tips?

So I am running it on oracle SQL developer. Version 17.4.1.054

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID,
       STREET_NAME,
       substr((STREET_NAME), 1, instr(ADDR_STREET_NAME, ' ')),
       substr((STREET_NAME), instr(STREET_NAME, ' '), instr(STREET_NAME, ' '))
FROM ACOUNT_TBL
WHERE REPLACE(substr((STREET_NAME), 1, instr(STREET_NAME, ' ')), ' ', '') = REPLACE(substr((STREET_NAME), instr(STREET_NAME, ' '), instr(STREET_NAME, ' ')), ' ', '')
  AND REPLACE(substr((ADDR_STREET_NAME), 1, instr(ADDR_STREET_NAME, ' ')), ' ', '')NOT LIKE '[^0-9]%';
```

This is the outcome

```
ACCOUNT_ID  STREET NAME       BEFORE SPACE        AFTER SPACE
1           Far Farm          Far                 Far
2           3 3 Station Road  3                   3
```

Far farm should not appear because i have set the like only numbers.But it does..

Comment: *"oracle SQL developer. Version 17.4.1.054"* then why did you tag SQL Server and not Oracle? They are completely different RDBMS.

Comment: Apologies. Can you answer my question?

Comment: I'm afraid not; it was the `sql-server` tag that initially got my attention, I'm not a Oracle user and know very little about Oracle.

Comment: The client doesn't really matter, the DBMS does, including the version you are using. Your code refers to both `STREET_NAME` and `ADDR_STREET_NAME` - are they different columns, or have you just recreated your query for posting inconsistently? (The table name looks wrong too).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> with test (street_name) as
  2    (select '9 9 House Road'    from dual union all
  3     select '30 Far Farm'       from dual union all
  4     select '902 902 My Street' from dual union all
  5     select 'Gump Road'         from dual
  6    )
  7  select street_name
  8  from test
  9  where regexp_like(street_name, '\d+ \d+');

STREET_NAME
-----------------
9 9 House Road
902 902 My Street

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to match a digit at the beginning followed by a space and then the same digit, you may use

```
select s,REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,'^(\d+) \1',1,1,null,1) as dig
from t;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cf397ea92110e94a058616f341cd6fdf)